# Summarizing one field using another as summary statistic using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, summarizing

I'm trying to replicate, using arcpy, the 'right-click - Summarize' function in ArcMap.
I want to specifically summarize column 'A' of my attribute table (this is a point layer), to get the count. But I also want to use column 'B' (area), and sum that for each category in A.

So far I've only found how to summarize A on it's own.

Any help?

This is the only related script I have found, but only does half the job:

```
def SumStats(shapeFile, fieldName):
sumDict = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapeFile,[fieldName]) as scurse:
    for row in scurse:
    if row[0] in sumDict:
        sumDict[row[0]] += 1
    else:
        sumDict[row[0]] = 1

tbl = arcpy.CreateTable_management("in_memory","MuchGIS")[0]

arcpy.AddField_management(tbl,"Item","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(tbl,"Count","SHORT")

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(tbl,["Item","Count"]) as icurse:
for k,v in sumDict.iteritems():
        icurse.insertRow((k,v,))
```

Comment: Updated - Thanks Alex, forgotten I could use that tool in model builder. Did that and exported as a script, working perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is already implemented within the `Summary Statistics (Analysis)` geoprocessing tool available in all license levels.

Answer (score 1):

You were most of the way there. Add both fields into the cursor and increment by area.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapeFile,['A','B']) as scurse:
    for row in scurse:
        if row[0] in sumDict:
            sumDict[row[0]] += row[1]
        else:
            sumDict[row[0]] = row[1]
```